# WCF service throwing authentication error on 1 server

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF Service thats deployed on 4 servers with load balancer.
Out of this 4, 1 of the server if its online throws below error.

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''
```

If that server is removed, rest 3 work fine but just 1 server has this issue.
Considering that the file and config is the same on all 4 servers, the only difference will be server or IIS setup.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the possible reason for this?

Its basicHttpBinding with
Server config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
</security>
```

Client Config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

Comment: What type of authentication you have configured on service application in IIS (e.g. Windows, Basic, digest,anonymous)? Is it same setting on all 4 servers?

Comment: @PankajKapare where would you find it in IIS configs?

Comment: check image from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Comment: @PankajKapare Anonymous authentication on all 4 servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in IIS authentication configuration. please open the authentication module in the IIS hosted application, and then enable the corresponding authentication mode.
[image]

The specific authentication support depends on your project authentication mode.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831496(v=ws.11)#Impersonation
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: The current setup is anonymous authentication on all 4 servers and it works fine on 3 of them.

Comment: Do you mean that if you send a separate request to this server, any client will generate this error? or there is a problem with one of the client credentials.

Comment: No. the requests are being sent through single url and the load balancer directs the request to 1 of the 4 servers. So if the load balancer only has 3 good servers, all service requests go through smoothly. But if the 4th bad server is added to the load balancer, some requests going to that server will fail with the error mentioned above.